# Error when using endfloat with unicode characters

Tags: unicode, endfloat

I have a problem with the endfloat package and unicode characters.  When I compile the following, everything works as expected:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\caption{Ö}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

However, when I also load the endfloat package (`\usepackage{endfloat}`), I get the following error message:

```
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:ÖÖ not set up for use with LaTeX.
```

This could be a bug, but my suspicion is that I'm making a mistake somewhere.  I'm hardly the first person to use special characters with the endfloat package.  However, the above example is so simple, I don't see where I could have made a mistake.  Any advice is appreciated.

Edit: The file is of course encoded using utf-8.

Comment: Looks like a bug more than a mistake. In absence of real solution, you can get out of trouble using `\"O` instead of `Ö` for captions.

Comment: @Fran Yes, it's a bug.

Comment: I just submitted a bug report to the maintainers of the package.

Comment: tmalsburg has submitted the bug to me and I have submitted it to the real maintainer of `endfloat`, offering that I'm willing to make the patch and publish the version to CTAN. (I have made releases of `endfloat` in the past with permission of the maintainer.) Unfortunately Jeff hasn't answered so far, so I just tried to contact him again. So please hold the line...

Comment: This is finally fixed in endfloat v2.6

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I solved the same problem in the GuIT forum about nine months ago recommending to make a bug report: see [Cambiare posizionamento immagini tutte alla fine del testo](http://www.guitex.org/home/forum/5-tex-e-latex/8662-cambiare-posizionamento-immagini-tutte-alla-fine-del-testo?lang=en#82101).

Where's the issue? The package `endfloat` uses `\write` for writing in its auxiliary files, whereas `\protected@write` should be used.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{endfloat}

% patch \efloat@iwrite to use \protected@write
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\efloat@iwrite[1]{%
   \immediate\expandafter\protected@write\csname efloat@post#1\endcsname{}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\caption{Ö}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```