# Problem with Swedish hyphenation using apa6 with \usepackage[swedish]{babel}

Tags: languages, babel, hyphenation, apa6

I can't seem to get Swedish hyphenation to work within the document when using the apa6 document class, though I am using the Swedish babel package.

The problem is *not citation related*, but concerns the actual *paper content*. I have not yet inserted any citations and I am having trouble already in the document preamble (see example below).

I have tried to use UTF-8 encoding, but that gives me error.

So far I have not seen anyone mentioning the same problem.

My question is simply: **How can I get Swedish hyphenation to work within the document?**

This is my best try of a minimal working example (**edit:** updated to contain a figure, that seems to be what is causing error):

```
\documentclass[man]{apa6}

\usepackage[swedish]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{Små söta röda rävar är överblivna från året}
\shorttitle{Små söta rävar}

\author{Malin Bergqvist}
\affiliation{Linköpings universitet}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{Old-Woman-Young-Woman.jpg}
\caption{En välkänd optisk illusion.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

**Update: The error I am getting:**

```
./main.fff:6:
Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:�lk not set up for use with LaTeX.
See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.6 \caption{En v�lk�nd optisk illusion.}

Your command was ignored.
Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command, or  <return>  to continue without it.
```

The attached image shows the results of the MWE.

All help is much appreciated, I am rather new to using LaTeX. Thank you!

[image: Example results]

Comment: The problems that are generated by your MWE would not appear to be related to hyphenation. Instead, they seem to be related to input and output encoding matters. Try adding the instructions `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` and `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` to the preamble and see if that fixes things. (You may also need to move the instruction `\begin{document}` to before the `\title` command.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have tried to use both \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} and \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}, but UTF-8 does not seem to be compatible with apa6 and gives an error. Should it normally work with the apa6 doc class? Moving \begin{document} does not seem to work either...

Comment: @Malin  I just tested your document with the two lines added, and it works just fine. Would you please update your question, with more information about which errors you get

Comment: You were right, Mico and @daleif, the MWE worked fine with the two lines added. I had only tried them on my real document, which also contained figures. It seems the error connets the UTF-8 encoding with the figure caption in Swedish. I updated my question with a figure in the MWE and the compile error message I got. Hope that clarifies better!

Comment: Using standard LaTeX encoding in the caption as in `v\"alk\"and` works.  The `apa` has some special processing of tables and figures that does not seem to cope correctly with your encoding.

Comment: Thanks for providing this updated/augmented MWE. The `apa6` document class loads the `caption` package internally. I have absolutely no idea why it's giving you this problem. A workaround -- not a real solution, just a workaround -- would be not to use characters with diacritics (Umlaute) in arguments of `\caption` commands and, instead, to write `\"{a}`, `\"{o}`, `\"{u}`, etc.

Comment: @Mico, it seems that `apa6` is writing the figure to an external file and then perhaps including it at the end, it gets an `.fff` extension. When I run the example, my emacs tells be that the `.fff` file is `latin1` not `utf8`, thus we get the problem, when the file is input later on.

Comment: Thank you so much for your advice, Andew, Mico and daleif. The workaround will definitely solve my problem for now!

Comment: @daleif - Many thanks for providing this analysis.

Answer (score 2):

It is not really a problem with `apa6`, but rather `endfloat` (which is loaded by `apa6`), as this example also crashes:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[swedish]{babel}

\usepackage{endfloat}

\begin{document}

sadfsadf

\begin{figure}
\centering
\rule{5cm}{5cm}
\caption{En välkänd optisk illusion.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

---

Update, Egreg actually have already given the answer in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/144425/3929

So simply add this to your preamble

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\efloat@iwrite[1]{%
   \immediate\expandafter\protected@write\csname efloat@post#1\endcsname{}}
\makeatother
```

and it compiles just fine

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks for linking and clarifying!