# Replace figures by Figure placeholder and move all of them to bottom in LaTeX

Tags: vertical-alignment, automation

I was asked by the journal to

> do not embed figures and tables in the manuscript file

Google says me only about [this](https://www.researchgate.net/post/Ive_written_my_research_paper_in_Latex_How_do_I_separate_tables_figures_from_the_manuscript_while_submitting_to_a_journal) solution.

However solution requires manual amendment of LaTeX file which I would like to avoid to do not remove too much content/do not broke LaTeX file.

I wonder if there is any command in LaTex to replace all content between *\begin{figure}* and *\end{figure}* with simple Figure X where X is a next consecutive number and move all of the figures/tables to the bottom.
... Or if there's any simpler solution

Comment: \usepackage{endfloat}

Comment: Seems that this package has problem with polish letters (ł, ć, ż, ó) in figure caption.

Immediately after adding it, I am unable to compile document. 
In log I see 'Undefined control sequence. and ' T1\l instead of ł

Should I add any option to this package?

Comment: I have following modules:

\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{graphicx,float,multirow}
\usepackage[caption = false]{subfig}
\usepackage{lineno,hyperref,amsmath}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[author={Mateusz Kędzior}]{pdfcomment}
\modulolinenumbers[1]

Comment: Hmmm... seems that I found a solution: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/144372/error-when-using-endfloat-with-unicode-characters